# How to find exact number of minimum values in matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, minimum

I want to find 3 minimum values in my matrix.

For example:

```
7 7 11 5 6
8 9 6 3 2 
10 15 8 3 4
12 9 6 8 11
```

3 minimum values: 2,3,4.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please consider accepting one of the answers below. As it stands, this question appears to be unanswered. Thanks! =)

Answer (score 3):

If the vector is large, sorting a matrix `(O(n*log n))` might take more time than doing three linear searches `(O(n))`. So something like this might actually be faster than sorting the array and selecting the first three values.

On my computer, this approach is faster on vectors larger than 1000-3000 elements.

```
num_vals = 3
vals = zeros(num_vals,1);
for k = 1:3
   [min_val, idx] = min(A);
   vals(ii) = min_val;
   A(idx) = NaN;
end
```

To illustrate:

```
A = rand(1e6,1);
S = A;

%% Linear search:
tic
for ii = 1:10
A = S;
num_vals = 3;
vals = zeros(num_vals,1);
for ii = 1:3
   [min_val, idx] = min(A);
   vals(ii) = min_val;
   A(idx) = NaN;
end
end
t1 = toc
A = S;

%% Sorting first:
tic
for ii = 1:10
   As = sort(A(:),'ascend');
   vals2 = As(1:3);
end
t2 = toc
isequal(vals, vals2)

t1 =
     0.0661
t2 =
     0.4781

ans =
     1
```

Comment: Just keep in mind you are changing vals with this solution - if vals is an input, changing it in this case will result in a copy being made. Perhaps OP doesn't mind, but something to consider.

Comment: Thanks for noting @siliconwafer. =) That's also the reason for the `A = S` line, to ensure the original vector is preserved. Maybe I should have called the vector where changes are made `A_temp` and kept the original unchanged, but ... =)

Comment: @OP: I just noticed (when editing) you had a matrix and not a vector as it looked like at first. Then you need to do: `[min_val, idx] = min(A(:));`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
nrItems = 3;
yourAr  = [ 7 7 11 5 6 8 9 6 3 2 10 15 8 3 4 12 9 6 8 11 ];
sortAr  = sort(yourAr, 'ascend');


vals    = sort(1:nrItems)
```